# How to connect LDAP with TLS by JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, jndi

When I try to connect an LDAP server with TLS enabled, it failed with the following exceptions.
Is there anything wrong with my my-ca.crt file?

```
public class LdapTest {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        LdapTest test = new LdapTest();
        test.tryit();
        System.out.println("Test End.");
    }

    public void tryit() throws Exception {      
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL,"ignore");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");
        String keystore = "/Users/dummy/Downloads/my-ca.crt";
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);

        DirContext ctx = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
            sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search("cn=Directory Manager", "objectClass=*", sc);
            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult searchResult = results.next();
                System.out.println("----------" + searchResult.toString() + "---------");
            }
        } catch (javax.naming.AuthenticationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ctx != null) {
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The exception]

Furthermore, I can connect to my LDAP server with a dummy DummySSLSocketFactory with the following settings:

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.REFERRAL,"ignore");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");
env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "com.test.ldap.DummySSLSocketFactory");
```

Comment: 'It failed' is not a problem description.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Post the exception **in your question**. Don't post pictures of text here, or, worse, still, evanescent links to them.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue by following steps

> Keytool -import -alias certificatekey -file my-ca.crt -keystore
>   my-ca.jks

Use the 'my-ca.jks' in Java code instead of 'my-ca.crt', then I can connect to my ldap server successfully.

```
String keystore = "/Users/dummy/Downloads/my-ca.jks";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keystore);
```